# What's the fastest memory card that can be used with a Canon S95 (P&S) digital camera?

Tags: canon, point-and-shoot, memory-card

The S95 can apparently accommodate [any of the following](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/digital_cameras/powershot_s95#Specifications): SD/SDHC Memory Card, SDXC Memory Card, MultiMediaCard, MMCplus Card, HC MMCplus Card.

Which one is going to be the fastest? I really want to minimize the time to take photos.

Of those choices, I've only used/heard of Secure Digital, so if I had to just pick one at random it would be one of those. "Class 10" SD sounds like the way to go.

Bonus questions: what's the safest bet as far as...

- working in a standard/off-the-shelf card reader?
- longevity?

Comment: Is there a reason you need the fastest? And what exactly are you trying to minimize? Because the delay between pressing the button and the picture being taken has nothing to do with your SD card. And the speed of the SD card will mostly be visible when you're copying the pictures onto your computer. Generally speaking, digital cameras record the picture into an internal memory buffer then write the picture from there onto the memory card; unless you take enough pictures to fill that buffer, or you try to turn off the camera right away, the memory card speed won't be a factor for you.

Comment: Ah, memory buffer. Of course. That totally helps, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain **SD** cards top out at 2GB; **SDHC** (Secure Digital High Capacity) gets you between 4GB and 16GB; **SDXC** (Secure Digital eXtended Capacity) gets you from 32GB to 2TB. In practical terms, you're going to be using SDHC cards most of the time -- under 4GB is kind of limiting, forcing you to carry a spare or two, and anything more than 16GB is too expensive to be practical unless you're dealing with a very-high-resolution camera and recording raw data.

The speed of the card is a separate deal. It's not directly related to the capacity.

As for MMC (MultiMedia Card), it's an obsolete format. The SD family shares the same physical layout and electrical contacts, so most SD card devices can also use MMC if you have old cards lying around.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Class 6 Transcend card in my S90 and it works great. As Stan pointed out, the format is a different topic. The class is what you want to look at for speed. I would get class 6 or higher(eg 10).